# Python - How to allow ABC subclasses to have custom additional parameters in __init__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, abc

Consider the following:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class ClassBase(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, name: str, value: int):
        pass

class Child1(ClassBase):
    def __init__(self, name: str, value: int, some_other_property: str):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.something = some_other_property

class Child2(ClassBase):
    def __init__(self, name: str, value: int, another_value: int):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.another = another_value
```

I want all classes that extend `ClassBase` ABC to include `name` and `value` parameters in their __init__ signature, and allow them to include some of their own parameters.

Is there a proper way to achieve this? I noticed that PyCharm IDE doesn't complain if the `__init__` method of children classes doesn't match the ABC's, but it does for other abstract methods

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't complain about the signature. It only checks to see the child classes *implement* those `abstractmethod`s. As long as your child classes implement all of the `abstractmethods`, then their instances are qualified to be a `ClassBase` object.

Comment: I was thinking about either adding `*args` or `**kwargs` into the abstract base class's init. Would that be considered bad practice?

Comment: @musava_ribica Actually there are some conventions, like if the method supposed to return an integer, it's better to return `0` in the body of the `abstractmethod`. It's a clue for subclasses. But about arguments of the init I have no Idea. Let's see others opinion about this.